# How to logs all rows affected after delete trigger on multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have table QuoteDetail with multiple rows with the same Quotation Number.
The records can be deleted using bulk delete 'Delete from QuoteDetail Where QuoteNo ='12345'
How can I logs all deleted rows using after delete trigger?
Below is my trigger script but only logs 1 row and the rest are discarded.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgcsms_QuoteDetail_DeleteLogs] ON [CSMS].[dbo].[QuoteDetail] 
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @QuoteNo varchar(50)
    DECLARE @SeqNo int
    DECLARE @ItemCode varchar(50)
    DECLARE @Qty float
    DECLARE @NetPrice float
    DECLARE @TotAmt float

    SELECT @QuoteNo = DELETED.[QuoteNo]
            ,@SeqNo = DELETED.[SeqNo]
            ,@ItemCode = DELETED.[ItemCode]
            ,@Qty = DELETED.[Qty]
            ,@TotAmt = DELETED.[TotAmt]
    FROM DELETED

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[QuoteDetailDeleteLogs]
           (
            [QuoteNo]
            ,[SeqNo]
            ,[ItemCode]
            ,[Qty]
            ,[TotAmt]
           )
           VALUES
           (
            @QuoteNo
            ,@SeqNo
            ,@ItemCode
            ,@Qty
            ,@NetPrice
            ,@TotAmt

           )
END
```

Comment: The problem here is your trigger is only expecting one row. Don't assign (or `DECLARE`) your values to variables, just `INSERT` them into your table.

Comment: @Larnu , it works like magic! Thank you for the great advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it righ. Just not using "@variables" and instead using tables. Because after all, you want multiple rows, right? That's also known as "a table".

Also worth noting - I took the liberty of upgrading your trigger to include UPDATE as well, because an update is a DELETE joined with an immediate INSERT afterwards. So I imagine if you update a line and QuoteNo (quote number) changed from '12345' to '54321' you would want that in your audit trail (your "QuoteDetailsLog").

[updated 30Aug2018 ]

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgcsms_QuoteDetail_DeleteLogs] ON [CSMS].[dbo]. 
[QuoteDetail] 
 AFTER DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[QuoteDetailDeleteLogs]
       (
        [QuoteNo]
        ,[SeqNo]
        ,[ItemCode]
        ,[Qty]
        ,[TotAmt]
       )
SELECT [QuoteNo]
        ,[SeqNo]
        ,[ItemCode]
        ,[Qty]
        ,[TotAmt]
FROM DELETED
END
```

keeping it short and simple

Comment: that is great buddy! Yes, I just wanted to load directly to logs table just to make sure if someone wanted to recover the details I still have the leverage. Your idea is appreciated.

Comment: No need to insert it into a temp table. Just select it within your insert statement from DELETED table.